# How to distribute passengers to flights using Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, node.js, arrays

I've got a project I'm working on that deals with managing flights and passenger numbers. I'm currently stuck implementing the function below, any suggestions for how I could go about this would be excellent, what I currently have is below which I don't think is correct, thanks again.

**Question:**

In the Passengers() function, write a distributeAllSeatsToAllPassengers() function that receives as parameters the number of VIP passengers, the number of regular passengers, the number of flights, the number of business seats per flight, and the number of economy seats per flight. It returns an object containing the following fields: VIP passengers with business seats; VIP passengers with economy seats; regular passengers with business seats; regular passengers with economy seats.

The distribution rules need to be followed in this order:

First, assign VIP passengers to business seats, until either the VIP passengers or the business seats are consumed.

Then, if there are still VIP passengers, assign them to economy seats, until either the VIP passengers or the economy seats are consumed.

Then, if there are still business seats, assign regular passengers to business seats, until either the regular passengers or the business seats are consumed.

Then, if there are still economy seats, assign regular passengers to economy seats, until either the regular passengers or the economy seats are consumed. You have to assign as many passengers as possible. There may be either passengers or seats that are left.

After the definition of the distributeAllSeatsToAllPassengers() function, a line of code will export the functions from the module: return {distributeAllSeatsToAllPassengers};

**My current solution:**

```
import { supportsEsModules } from "mocha/lib/utils";

function Passengers() {

    function distributeAllSeatsToAllPassengers(vipPassengers, 
        regularPassengers, nrOfFlights, businessSeatsPerFlight, economySeatsPerFlight)
    { 
        let vipPassengersAssignedToBusinessSeats = 0;
        let vipPassengersAssignedToEconomySeats = 0;
        let regularPassengersAssignedToBusinessSeats = 0;

        vipPassengersAssignedToBusinessSeats = vipPassengers / businessSeatsPerFlight;
        vipPassengersNotSeated = vipPassengers % businessSeatsPerFlight;
        
        
        if (vipPassengersNotSeated !== 0)
        {
            vipPassengersAssignedToEconomySeats = vipPassengersNotSeated / economySeatsPerFlight;
            vipPassengersStillNotSeated = vipPassengersNotSeated % economySeatsPerFlight;
        }

        if (businessSeatsPerFlight !== 0)
        {
            regularPassengersAssignedToBusinessSeats = regularPassengers / businessSeatsPerFlight;
            regularPassengersNotSeated = regularPassengers % businessSeatsPerFlight;
        }

        if (economySeatsPerFlight !== 0)
        {
            regualarPassengersAssignedToEconomySeats = regularPassengersNotSeated / economySeatsPerFlight;
            regularPassengersStillNotSeated = regularPassengersNotSeated % economySeatsPerFlight;
        }

        var distributedPassengers = {
            vipPassengersWithBusinessSeats: vipPassengersAssignedToBusinessSeats,
            vipPassengersWithEconomySeats: vipPassengersAssignedToEconomySeats,
            regularPassengersWithBusinessSeats: regularPassengersAssignedToBusinessSeats,
            regularPassengersWithEconomySeats: regularPassengersAssignedToEconomySeats
        };
        return { distributedPassengers };

    }
    return { distributeAllSeatsToAllPassengers };
}

module.exports = Passengers();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i came up with, i don't know if it is according to your teacher's (i assume) guidelines, but it should work. Maybe usable as a starting point. I added explanations.

The problem with your line `vipPassengersAssignedToBusinessSeats = vipPassengers / businessSeatsPerFlight;` is that you might get back a float number. Picture having 3 vip passengers and 2 business seats - 3/2 returns a float. I would use loops for the issue.

Disclaimer: Not tested, and I have not used `%` operator before, but I am sure you can adapt.

```
function Passengers() {

function distributeAllSeatsToAllPassengers(num_flights, economy_seats, business_seats, passengers_vip, passengers_regular) {

    // number of flights is completely redundant in this example
    
    let passengers_vip_seated_business = 0,
        passengers_vip_seated_economy = 0,
        passengers_regular_seated_business = 0,
        passengers_regular_seated_economy = 0,
        passengers_vip_unseated = 0, // not necessary but nice to have
        passengers_economy_unseated = 0; // see above

    // use a for..of loop, assuming passengers_vip is an array
    for (let passenger of passengers_vip) {
        if (business_seats > 0) {
            business_seats--; // reduce number of available business seats
            passengers_vip_seated_business++; // increase number of seated passengers
        } else if (economy_seats > 0) {
            // if there are no business seats available, assign to economy_seats
            economy_seats--;
            passengers_vip_seated_economy++;
        } else {
            // no more seats, bummer!
            passengers_vip_unseated++;
        }
    }
    // do the same for regular passengers
    for (let passenger of passengers_regular) {
        if (business_seats > 0) {
            business_seats--; // reduce number of available business seats
            passengers_regular_seated_business++; // increase number of seated passengers
        } else if (economy_seats > 0) {
            // if there are no business seats available, assign to economy_seats
            economy_seats--;
            passengers_regular_seated_economy++;
        } else {
            // no more seats, bummer!
            passengers_economy_unseated++;
        }
    }
    
    return {
        passengers_vip_seated_business: passengers_vip_seated_business,
        passengers_vip_seated_economy: passengers_vip_seated_economy,
        passengers_regular_seated_business: passengers_regular_seated_business,
        passengers_regular_seated_economy: passengers_regular_seated_economy
    }
}

// returns the function, idk why but okay, maybe for functional programming
return {distributeAllSeatsToAllPassengers}
}
```

Comment: Hey @Lalalena, thank you for answering this question. This is very good as a starting point, which I'm now going to tweak, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Working through this question too, and viewing your workings, I came up with this solution using ternary operators that I thought may be helpful to share:

```
 function distributeAllSeatsToAllPassengers(VIPPassengers,RegPassengers,businessSeats,EconoSeats) {
          
        if (( VIPPassengers + RegPassengers) > (businessSeats + EconoSeats))
        { return 'Error: Passengers exceed number of seats'};

         VIPinBus = (VIPPassengers <= businessSeats) ? VIPPassengers : businessSeats;
         VIPinEcono = (VIPPassengers > businessSeats) ? (VIPPassengers-businessSeats) : "none";
         RegInBus = (RegPassengers <= (businessSeats - VIPPassengers)) ? RegPassengers : (VIPPassengers < businessSeats) ? (businessSeats - VIPPassengers) :  "none";
         RegInEcono = (RegInBus > 0 ) ? RegPassengers - RegInBus : RegPassengers;

         let distrubutedPassengers = {
            VIPPassengersInBusiness: VIPinBus,
            VIPPassengersInEconomy: VIPinEcono,
            RegularPassengersInBusiness: RegInBus,
            RegularPassengersInEconomy: RegInEcono
         };
         return {distrubutedPassengers};     
     }
     console.log(distributeAllSeatsToAllPassengers(50,50,30,70));
```